# Webpack 4 Error "Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:3) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type." when trying to pack CSS

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader

When I build my webpack module, CSS file doesn't work.
"Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "webpack": "^4.20.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
module.export = {
    entry: './src/index.js',

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'main.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    devServer:{
        overlay: true
    },
    module: {
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:{
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]

            }       
        ]
    }   
}
```

I think style-loader doesn't work, but I don't know why. Please, help!

Comment: Are you using SASS or LESS or just trying to process a pure .css file? Also, you may want to try using "include" to isolate the problematic file. For example: 
test: /\.css$/,
include: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/assets') // The folder containing your .css files